# Share variable from .py to .html in Angular

Tags: python, angular, flask, web-scraping

So I am developing a Web App with angular and Spring 5 for a benchmarking project application for my company. In this webapp home page, there is a "latest news" component where I want to display links from the official website of the project.

I was able to get those links with a python file I added to my project folder. I stored those links in an list. 
Now, I can't figure out how to get this list in my html file to display it in my website.

If you have any suggestion of how to do this, or if you thinks there's a better way, please let me know.

Here is my Python code:

```
> from flask import Flask, render_template from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> import requests
> 
> source = requests.get('http://eurobench2020.eu/').text soup =
> BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml') news =
> soup.find(id="recent-posts-3").select('a')
> 
> oui = [] i = 0 for link in news:
>     oui.append(link.get('href'))
>     print(i)
>     print(link.get('href'))
>     i = i+1 print(oui)
> 
> app = Flask(__name__) @app.route('/')
> 
> def index():
>     return render_template('index.html', oui = oui) app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to display "oui" list in my html

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far? We'd be able to help you better if you do that.

Comment: Trying to share a variable between different programming frameworks is quite impractical. I think the most practical solution for you would be to modify your python script to write the content of the list with the links to a JSON file; store that file somewhere your web-app can access it; then get your webapp to load the links from the JSON file.

Comment: posted the ython code @YogeshSudheerModak

Comment: @Danoram I found on the internet an article that manages sharing between python and html, but only with a single index.html, stored in a "templates" folder

Comment: I don't know anything about the Flask framework but I've added it as a tag so hopefully more people can see your question and help you find an answer.

Comment: Did my answer below work? If so, please accept! If not, let me know!

Comment: Hi @A.Pine, sorry I had not seen your answer, thanks anyway for answering. To be honest, I didn't try it, I changed the technique, and did not use flask at all. I did what Danoram suggested: storing the links in a JSON file, and get the data from it.

Comment: @Danoram, I did your way eventually, but I'm not able to access the links in the html file, should I open a new Question, or is it okay here?

Comment: Questions usually get most of their views in the first few hours of being posted. If you update this question it probably won't be seen by very many people. I'd recommend making a new question with your new problem of accessing the links in the html file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your data directly into a template, you basically have the right idea:

You have a `app.py` file and a `templates` directory with an `index.html` template.

```
├── app.py
├── templates
    └── index.html
```

For your `app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://eurobench2020.eu/').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml') 
news = soup.find(id="recent-posts-3").select('a')

oui = []
for link in news:
    oui.append(link.get('href'))

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=dict(oui=oui))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For your `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Here's your data</p>
        <ul>
            {% for link in data.oui %}
            <li>
                <a href='{{link}}'>{{link}}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As others mentioned though, if you want to use this with Angular or some other web framework that has its own templating and you don't want to use Python & Jinja2 for templating, you should expose your data as a resource with an API. In this case you would want to pip install flask-restful and change your `app.py` to something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://eurobench2020.eu/').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml') 
news = soup.find(id="recent-posts-3").select('a')

oui = []
for link in news:
    oui.append(link.get('href'))

app = Flask(__name__) 
api = Api(app)

class OuiData(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return jsonify(oui)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=dict(oui=oui))

api.add_resource(OuiData, '/api/oui')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then you can get the data in an Angular service as follows:

```js
getOuiData(): Observable<HttpResponse<OuiData>> {
  return this.http.get<OuiData>('http://localhost:5000/api/oui');
}
getOuiData().subscribe(x => { console.log(x); } )
```